# Finding coefficient of a function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Consider the generating function   $g(x)=\frac{(1+x)(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^2}{(1-x)^4}$
>
> Determinate the coefficient of $x^{15}$

First of all I'm very new in Discrete Mathemathics, I'm taking this subject for the first  time. I got some exercises from my teacher and I'm trying to do them. I have no idea how to start on this type of problem. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could start by considering what are the ways to obtain $15$ summing integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

If you have a sequence $A = (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, the function
$$
G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n
$$
is called the *generating function* for the sequence $A$.

You are looking for the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in $g(x)$ you are given. Construct its MacLaurin series, and you will get the coefficient.

It will help to know a couple useful generating functions, e.g.
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint...You could start by extracting the factor $x^2$ and simplifying the expression, so that you are looking for the coefficient of $x^{13}$ in the expansion of $$\frac{(1+x)^3(1+x^2)^2}{(1-x)^4}$$

So now you have seven terms to find and add up...

Comment: How did you get to that expression? How did you extract $x^2$?

Comment: Yes and I simplified the larger bracketed term using the formula for the sum of a geometric series